# How can I use one variable from a class in another

Tags: java

So I have 2 classes. Interaction and Game. Game calls methods in Interaction that return an output. An example of a method is walk. Game has a variable time. I need the walk method to be able to change the value of time such as time = time - 1;

How can I do this. Game is already a subclass of Interaction which allows it to use the methods.

Comment: Is it `Game extends Interaction` !! Put some whatever code effort you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. You need to have setter and getter methods on Game. You need to make those methods public. You should be able to access those methods from Interaction for game object.

If you have the time variable protected/public, you should be able to access the variable directly from Game.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever class your calling from create an instance of that class in the other class:

```
Game game = new Game();

then use methods from within the game class:

int time = game.walk();
```

Or vice versa:

```
Interaction interaction = new Interaction();

interaction.walk;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this if game is subclass of Interaction :

```
public class Interaction {
    game g = new game();

    public void walk(){
        System.out.println(g.getTime() - 1);
    }    
    public class game{
        int time;
        public int getTime() {
            return time;
        }
        public void setTime(int time) {
            this.time = time;
        }
    }
}
```

in other class you can easily do :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Interaction interaction = new Interaction();
    interaction.g.setTime(10);
    interaction.walk();
}
```

do you want something like this ? or else then post.

[Here's](http://ideone.com/XEOdF5) running code. (I have just make `Interaction class static`).
I have just print result on console, you can return it & do as you want.